# jQuery UI ajax tabs and granular cache control of content

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, caching

I am using jQuery UI tabs with ajax content injected into a DIV, not an IFRAME.

The content is stored on the server as a text file consisting of HTML markup but the file lacks a DOCTYPE declaration, a HEAD section, a BODY section' it's basically

```
  <DIV>lorem ipse</DIV>.
```

I tried this approach to force a no-caching scenario:

```
 $("#tabs").tabs(
    {
    cache: false,
    ajaxOptions: {cache: false}
    }
);
```

But when I look at the Caching tab in Fiddler it says this:

HTTP/200 responses are cacheable by default, unless Expires, Pragma, 
   or Cache-Control headers are   present and forbid caching.
   HTTP/1.1 ETAG Header is present: "53a38d5790b2cc1:ab2"
   HTTP Last-Modified Header is present: Sun, 04 Dec 2011 14:23:50 GMT

No Explicit HTTP Expiration information was provided. 
   Most browsers utilize heuristic expiration policies:
   10% of the delta between Last-Modified and Date is '00:20:13' 
   so this response will heuristically expire 12/4/2011 1:08:26 PM.

How can this specific content be kept as no-cache?

P.S. In response to @Mikael's point that it's common to add some kind of changing value to the URL to prevent caching, I'm not quite sure how to do that when using the jQuery ajax declarative approach:

```
<div id='tabs' class="ui-tabs">

   <ul>
       <li><a title="contentcontainer" href="foo.html">One</a></li>
   <li><a title="contentcontainer" href="foo2.html">Two</a></li>        
   <li><a title="contentcontainer" href="foo3.html">Three</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id='contentcontainer'></div>
 </div>
```

How to append `'?' + new Date().getTime().toString()` to the href URL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what causes caching in this case.

However when dealing with ajax requests one popular approach to prevent caching is to add random or timestamp parameter to URL. e.g. to request  /public/static_file?_=1239871984 instead of /public/static_file

Another way to prevent it could be to add expiration header, which does not work that well with some browsers (if I recall correctly IE8 had really aggressive ajax caching).

Same approach works also for forcing refresh for js/css files when site is updated.